# Select columns from a table based on incoming column names from another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table "my_table" which has columns "parent_table" and "res_table_cols". The "res_table_cols" contains some column names from the parent table which is specified by the "parent_table".

I want to create a view/table so that it will contain only the data from the parent table for which the columns are defined in the "res_table_cols".

I am doing this in snowflake.

Eg.

parent_table

| name | age | sex | occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 27 | M | worker |
| mno | 34 | F | student |
| pqr | 42 | M | worker |

=============================================

my_table

| parent_table | res_table_cols |
| --- | --- |
| stage_table | name, age |

== == ===

I can also define the "res_table_cols" as an array and store the values as

| parent_table | res_table_cols |
| --- | --- |
| stage_table | ["name", "age"] |

===================================================

Result view/table output:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 27 |
| mno | 34 |
| pqr | 42 |

Comment: You need to fix your database design.  _Don't_ store CSV values in your tables, and use proper joins to relate one table to another.

Comment: You need to construct the query in your application and then run it (basically dynamic SQL).  You could return the results as a JSON data structure, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you are missing the ability of modern SQL to deal with nested data. Nothing wrong with that per-se.

Comment: And as @GordonLinoff says, the real problem with SQL is writing a query that will return an unknown set of columns -- hence the need to use dynamic SQL -- unless the OP is ok with getting a JSON data structured instead of columns.

Comment: So we need @Rajat Biswas to tell us what solutions are ok for them.